# Show installation date of packages installed with Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

Homebrew shows me all packages that I have installed with `brew leaves`. However, it doesn't show me when was a package been installed.

Is it possible to make Homebrew show the installation date of packages?

Answer (score 19):

`brew ls -lt` lists installed packages, sorted by **last modified date** of the package installation directory, newest to oldest.

Equivalent results can be obtained with:

```
find "$(brew --cellar)" -type d -maxdepth 0 | xargs ls -lt
```

With this incantation, sort order can be changed by adding `-U` (creation date) or `-u` (last access date) to the `ls -lt`

```
$ find "$(brew --cellar)" -type d -maxdepth 0 | xargs ls -ltU # creation aka *installation date*
$ find "$(brew --cellar)" -type d -maxdepth 0 | xargs ls -ltu # last access aka last use date
```

Add `-r` to `ls -lt` to reverse order, oldest to newest.

`brew ls -l` lists installed packages in alphabetical order.

It's unknown to me whether Homebrew affects a package folder's creation date during `brew upgrade`, so be aware that learning the *first* installation date of a package may be elusive.

The `-a` option for `brew ls -l` appears to be no longer available.

Comment: What did the `-a` option use to do?

Answer (score 6):

1. **`brew list`** and **`brew ls`** both are to see only the list of  all installed packages.
2. **`brew ls -l`** is to see the list of installed packages with date.
3. **`brew ls -lt`** to see list of order by installation date.

Comment: this was somewhat useful for me (so I voted up).  An issue is there is no actual `-a` option although `-l` works and will show a modified date.  `brew ls` also appears to be the same as `brew list`, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `brew ls -l` worked for me, but `brew ls -la` did not.

Answer (score 2):

Building off [@Kevin-Prichard's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/352335/406823), for anybody here in 2021.

`brew ls --formula -lt`

#### Variations

- Reverse order: `brew ls --formula -ltr`
- Only print package names: `brew ls --formula -t`
- Print 1 package name per line (useful for scripts): `brew ls --formula -t1`

#### Options

(from `brew ls -h`, with notes)

- `--formula`: `brew` requires the `--formula` flag when using `-l` or `-t` nowadays. Not sure when that started, but I'm on brew 3.0.1 so probably applies to versions >3.0. I'd guess this is to differentiate listing formulae vs casks (doesn't look like `-lt` are supported with `--cask`)
- `-l`: List formulae in long-format (i.e. with "last modified" date, akin to `ls -l`)
- `-t`: Sort formulae by time modified, listing most recently modified first.
- `-r`: Reverse the order of the formulae sort to list the oldest entries first. Note: make sure to use the -t flag with this one, to reverse by last-modified.
- `-1`: Force output to be one entry per line. This is the default when output is not to a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The following code sorts packages that were **manually installed** (via `brew install`) by the time they were last installed/upgraded/reinstalled.

Works in `bash` and `zsh`.

Assumes package dirpaths never contain whitespaces, and that at least one package has been installed with `brew install`.

```
# Manually installed packages (with "brew install").
pkgs=$(brew leaves --installed-on-request)

# Birthtimes / creation times of dirs of installed packages.
btimes=()
while read -r btime; do
    btimes+=( $(date -r $btime +%Y-%m-%d) )
done < <(stat -f %B $(brew --prefix $(printf %s "$pkgs")))

# Sort packages by time of last install/upgrade/reinstall.
paste -d ' ' <(printf "%s\n" "${btimes[@]}") <(printf %s "$pkgs") | sort
```

Sample output:

```
...
2022-12-06 gnu-sed
2022-12-25 bash
2022-12-25 shellcheck
2023-02-17 nano
2023-03-04 csvkit
...
```